# Testing if user input is an int or a str, then failing if input is a str. I keep getting strs I enter as undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to test if my user input is a string or an integer.

```
feet = input ("Enter your feet.")
inches = input ("Enter your inches.")

if type(eval(feet)) and type(eval(inches)) == int:
    print ("both are numbers!")
else:
    print ("That's not a Number!")
```

Here is my code, it works if I enter numbers for the values for feet and inches. However, if feet = a I get an error stating that a is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside: `if type(eval(feet)) and type(eval(inches)) == int` means `if bool(type(eval(feet))) and (type(eval(inches)) == int)`.  It does not mean `if type(eval(feet)) == int and type(eval(inches)) == int`.

Comment: Or more succinctly:  `x and y == z` means `bool(x) and (y == z)` not `(x == z) and (y == z)`  If you need to test multiple items you can do `all(item==z for item in (x, y))`.  If you need all items to be the same you can do `{x, y} == {z}`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing wrong is using `eval`. That's never a good way to do anything.

Instead, try to convert to int and catch the exception:

```
try:
    feet = int(feet)
    inches = int(inches)
except ValueError:
    print("not numbers!")
else:
    print("numbers!")
```

Comment: interesting! I have never heard of the Try command. Granted I am very new to python.  Is there a good source to read about this method? I would like to understand what is going on more.

Comment: @WynnBoss See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try or https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval` to test if user input is an integer. You get an error because the interpreter is trying to find a variable called `a` but there isn't one defined. Instead you can check if a string only contains digits.

```
def is_integer(s):
    for c in s:
        if not c.isdigit():
            return False
    return True

feet = input ("Enter your feet.")
inches = input ("Enter your inches.")

if is_integer(feet) and is_integer(inches):
    print ("both are numbers!")
else:
    print ("That's not a Number!")
```

This assumes that negative numbers are invalid.

Comment: Isn't it isdigit not isDigit? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit